# javascript : pass an array to WCF service (c#)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, wcf

I am trying to send an array to a wcf service.

My javascript :

```
var listoffice = new Array();

var office1 = { officeid : "1", officename : "Bat Cave" };
var office2 = { officeid : "2", officename : "Robin House" };

listoffice[0] = office1;
listoffice[1] = office2;

$.getJSON("ContactService.svc/createnewAwesomeoffice", { listoffice: listoffice }, function (data) {
   ...           
});
```

Here's the service :

```
public struct officetoadd
{
     public string officeid;
     public string officename;
}

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void createnewAwesomeoffice(List<officetoadd> listoffice)
{
   ...
}
```

the problem is the listoffice(in the service) is always null. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution by myself. I think this is pertinent to write it here, so it may help other people.

I simply had to convert my array to JSON with this :

```
var arrayjson = JSON.stringify(listoffice);
```

And then pass it to the WCF service :

```
$.getJSON("ContactService.svc/createnewAwesomeoffice", { listoffice: arrayjson }, function (data) {
   ...           
});
```

**Note:** *The JSON object is now part of most modern web browsers (IE 8 & above).*

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to put RequestFormat as well in your WebGetAttribute... Also, you may want to try turning "officetoadd" into a class and decorate it with DataContract and DataMember Attributes.

```
[DataContract]
public class officetoadd
{
     [DataMember]
     public string officeid;
     [DataMember]
     public string officename;
}

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(RequestFormat - WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void createnewAwesomeoffice(List<officetoadd> listoffice)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ty a lot for your suggestion, but I simply use JSON.stringify.

Comment: Can I set the parameter as `IEnumerable<T>` or any other interface or a `class` that is more primitive than `List<T>`?